# How to hide a progress bar when a button is clicked in a table,Data is dynamically got from server(loop repetition)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

*How to hide a progress bar when a button is clicked in a table,Data is dynamically got from server(loop repetition)*
[image]

*The above image shows how my page looks like.If i click on View All,that partcular progress bar should hide.I have a code which gives if i click on view all whole table progress bars data is hiding and showing.But I have to change that table row progress bar only*

**Html:-**

```
<span name="answer" onclick="ShowDiv()" style="margin-left:20%;">View All</span>
```

**Script:-**

```
function ShowDiv() {

var x = document.getElementById('myDiv');
if (x.style.display === 'none') {
    x.style.display = 'block';
} else {
    x.style.display = 'none';
}
```

**This div should hide and replace**

```
<div id="myDiv" class="description" style="padding-top:16px; font-weight: 900;font-style: italic;display:none;" ng-repeat="work in candidate.workflow" ng-if="$index > 0">                                                                  <uib-accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
                               <uib-accordion-group heading="{{group.title}}" ng-repeat="group in groups"> {{group.content}} </uib-accordion-group>
                             <dl   class="dl-horizontal text-sm" > 
                              <ol class="progtrckr"   >
                                <li ng-repeat="stage in work.stages" class="{{stage.status}}" ></li>

                            </ol>
                            <ol class="progtrckr">
                                <li ng-repeat="stage in work.stages" >{{stage.title}} </li>
                            </ol>

                            </dl>
                         </div>
```

**Here is My JSON**

```
  "list": [
{
  "candidateId": "137845432818",
  "name": "Robert D'souza",
  "role": "UI / UX Designer & Developer",
  "workflow": [
    {
      "vacancy": {

        "title": "For Profile Updation",
        "jobCode": null,
        "orgName": "Okcygenio"
      },
      "order": 10,
      "currentStatusId": 101,
      "currentStatus": "Sourcing",
      "stages": [
        {

          "title": "Sourcing",
          "order": 1,
          "stageTypeId": "1"
        },
        {

          "title": "MJB Screening",

          "stageTypeId": "10"
        },
        {

          "title": "Send JD",

          "stageTypeId": "7"
        },
        {

          "title": "Screening",

          "status":"progtrckr-todo"
        },
        {

          "title": "First Round",

          "status":"progtrckr-todo"
        },
        {

          "title": "Second Round",

          "status":"progtrckr-todo"
        },
        {

          "title": "Third Round",

         "status":"progtrckr-todo"
        },
        {

          "title": "HR Round",

          "status":"progtrckr-todo"
        },
        {

          "title": "Offer",

          "status":"progtrckr-todo"
        },
        {

          "title": "Join",

          "status":"progtrckr-todo"
        }
      ],
      "currentStageId": 5840
    }
  ]

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use ng-if to show or hide the div

```
<span name="answer" ng-click="ShowDiv()" style="margin-left:20%;">View All</span>

$scope.ShowDiv = function() {
   $scope.showProgress = false;
}
```

add ng-if to div like this

```
<div ng-if="showProgress || $index > 0" id="myDiv" class="description" style="padding-top:16px; font-weight: 900;font-style: italic;display:none;" ng-repeat="work in candidate.workflow" >



<div ng-if="showProgress || $index > 0" id="myDiv" class="description" style="padding-top:16px; font-weight: 900;font-style: italic;display:none;" ng-repeat="work in candidate.workflow" >
   <uib-accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
   <uib-accordion-group heading="{{group.title}}" ng-repeat="group in groups"> {{group.content}} </uib-accordion-group>
   <dl   class="dl-horizontal text-sm" >
      <ol class="progtrckr"   >
         <li ng-repeat="stage in work.stages" class="{{stage.status}}" ></li>
      </ol>
      <ol class="progtrckr">
         <li ng-repeat="stage in work.stages" >{{stage.title}} </li>
      </ol>
   </dl>
</div>
```

edited

create a additional property in your objects and assign values initially false. lets call that variable `showAll`.

change the div like this

```
<div ng-if="candidate.showAll || $index > 0"
```

in the ng click pass the index as parameter to the function

```
ng-click="ShowDiv($index)"
```

inside the function change the property value to false

```
$scope.ShowDiv = function(index) {
   $scope.candidate[index].showAll= false; // i'm assuming this is your array 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for Quick Response sachila ranawaka .I tried it it didn't work.

Comment: can you create a plnkr

Comment: if i click on View All (In a TableRow) the progress bar in that row only should hide remaining shuld show

Comment: Thank you sachila ranawaka will update and let u know

Comment: sachila ranawaka based on candidate id should hide and show progress bar.i edited JSON above please see that and let me know

Comment: Here is My Planker As Static Code https://plnkr.co/edit/s5eE5wJmEQN6QUaoaIEK?p=preview